# General question about configmaps and secrets in k8's space

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, openshift, secret-key

What are the differences between config maps and secrets in k8's space, does service accounts need to be associated with these resources to work? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

ConfigMap and secrets are used to decouple the application  configuration, database passwords, certificates etc from the image.

ConfigMap is used to store config files, properties file and so on. On the other hand secrets are used to store sensitive information like passwords, ssl certificates.

You can load key value pairs from these objects as environment variables inside the container or these objects can be mounted as volumes inside a container..

Service account is a different object and is not directly associated with these objects. Sa is part of RBAC. And can be granted access to list secrets or configMap at namespace level or cluster level depending on the roles

Answer (score 1):

Secrets are used for fields you want to hide like passwords, user and endpoints.

Using the docs:

> Kubernetes secret objects let you store and manage sensitive
>   information, such as passwords, OAuth tokens, and ssh keys. Putting
>   this information in a secret is safer and more flexible than putting
>   it verbatim in a Pod Lifecycle definition or in a container image

source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Config Maps are used for configuration inside the pod, like level of debugging or version of an external API called. It is a good practice for decoupling your code from your configuration, which can change from time to time.

source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

Comment: How does Service account come into picture here? Does it connect these resources in NameSpace level ?